# File Upload in WAS 8.5 not working

Tags: java, spring, websphere, multipart, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to upload one file from out application and its developed in Spring and uses apache commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar for Multipart file upload.
Earlier the file upload used to work but suddenly its stopped. I pointed my debug to WAS and tried to debug the application, the method which sets the file is below

```
@ResponseBody ActionResult uploadFile(TaskStatusBean command,BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request)
```

cannot give further information on method for security reasons

which sets the file inside the command object and later we retrieve using below call

```
MultipartFile file = command.getFile();
```

without a doubt it works perfectly in tomcat but it seems this `command.getFile()` statement gives null object in websphere. and below are the logs which I got in **SystemOut.log**

> ************ Start Display Current Environment ************
>
> ```
> WebSphere Platform 8.5.0.0 [BASE 8.5.0.0 gm1218.01]
> Host Operating System is Linux, version 3.10.0-121.el7.x86_64
> Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
> was.install.root = 
> user.install.root = 
> Java Home = /data1/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre
> Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626-20120304.00
> ************* End Display Current Environment *************
> ```
>
> [2/8/17 16:50:31:531 IST] 000000ca webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet     Error]-[springDispatcher]:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0209E: Writer     already
>   obtained at 
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getOutputStream(SRTServletResponse.java:743)
>   at
>   org.owasp.csrfguard.http.MutableHttpResponse.writeContent(MutableHttpResponse.java:99)
>     at
>   org.owasp.csrfguard.CSRFGuardFilter.doFilter(CSRFGuardFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
>
> [2/8/17 16:50:31:559 IST] 000000ca webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page
>   Exception: [2/8/17 16:50:31:981 IST] 000000b8 WSCallHelper  I
>   Calling getNativeConnection [2/8/17 16:50:33:731 IST] 000000a9 srt
>   W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setIntHeader
>   SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.

Any help appreciated. I am unable to get rid of this issue .
Thanks in advance

Regards,
Same

Comment: You mentioned that this used to work. Have you tried checking if WAS completely cleared your previously deployed class files? WAS has a nasty habit of keeping files around after redeploying them. It usually starts doing this after repeated deployments.

Comment: Yes it used to work. I received this error on older profile and then I created new profile .There I deployed new war and it worked properly. After a day it suddenly stopped working. Next to that I deployed redeployed latest war renaming it but issue still persist.

Comment: I haven't used WAS for three years but it sounds like you're also experiencing the same issue I had back then. You may need to check the profile for any orphaned class files. If I recall, it stored them in two or three locations.

Comment: Sorry Brother no success So far.. Even I tried applying latest patch on WAS 8.5.5.11 also tried Reinstalling the WAS application.

Comment: I don't think a patch would fix it as what a WAS administrator explained to me, this isn't a bug. It's part of the caching feature or something good like it. Have you tried deploying it under a different deployment name?

Comment: Yes.. It didn't worked either...We stopped at this stage...  Now I am uploading the files locally from my machine.